# How can I auto save a captured image in a UWP app?

Tags: image, uwp, save, storagefile

I have this code:

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

How can I implement to auto save image option when click on the capture button?

Comment: I fixed your post, but I am not sure it is okay what I did with the code in it. Check the last line and fix it if you need.

Comment: @peterh `await` and `captureUI` should have a space.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I implement to auto save image option when click on the capture button?

The StorageFile containing the captured photo is given a dynamically generated name and saved in our app's local folder if we do not cancel the capture, so if we click on the capture button without clicking the confirm button, the photo will be saved automatically in our app's TempState folder.

For more info, refer [Capture photos and video with Windows built-in camera UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui).

To better organize your captured photos, you may want to move the file to a different folder. Please refer to the following sample which shows how to copy the latest capture photo from the TempState folder to the LocalFolder.

For example:

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
var allFiles =await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (StorageFile item in allFiles.OrderByDescending(a => a.DateCreated))
    {
        StorageFolder destinationFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await item.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await item.DeleteAsync();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks and what I need to do is, when click on capture button it ask to confirm the photo, then it save. need to skip confirm part and when click on the capture button photo should automatically save.

Comment: @IndikaPrashad  When we click the on the capture button, it has saved the photo. If we do not click the confirm button, it also save the photo. You can test it without click the confirm button, you will see that photo in the TempState folder.

Comment: @IndikaPrashad I have updated the answer, please check it.